# C# Sorting DateTime issue

Tags: c#, list, datetime, sorting

I am setting up a list of date times:

```
DateTime a1
DateTime a2
DateTime a3
DateTime a4
```

The above looks like this (as DateTime objects):

```
3/1/2012 10:56
3/1/2012 17:03
3/1/2012 1:38
3/1/2012 5:33
```

Then I put them in a list and sort:

```
List<DateTime> ldtBites = new List<DateTime>();
ldtBites.Add(a1);
ldtBites.Add(a2);
ldtBites.Add(a3);
ldtBites.Add(a4);
ldtBites.Sort();
```

After Sorting I get this:

```
3/1/2012 1:38:00 AM
3/1/2012 10:56 AM
3/1/2012 5:03:00 PM
3/1/2012 5:33:00 AM
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  Running the code you post above sorts the dates properly.  At first glance it appears to be sorting alphabetically.  How are you outputting the list?

Comment: @Shannon: are you certain that the last result is actually 3/1? When I tested your code, I made a mistake that caused the results to come out in your order, except that the last row was 3/2/2012 instead. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You omitted the definition of w,x,y,z. I defined them as such:

```
DateTime w = new DateTime(2012, 3, 1, 10, 56, 0);
DateTime x = new DateTime(2012, 3, 1, 17, 3, 0);
DateTime y = new DateTime(2012, 3, 1, 1, 38, 0);
DateTime z = new DateTime(2012, 2, 29, 17, 3, 0);
```

This causes them to match your values for a1-a4; however, when I run the rest of your code, they sort correctly (a3, a4, a1, a2).

However, I noticed that x and z were the same hour/minute, so my initial test had this:

```
DateTime z = new DateTime(2012, 3, 1, 17, 3, 0);
```

When I ran this, I got them to come out in the order you were showing (a3, a1, a2, a4); however, after the `AddHours()` call went through, the `z` value was actually **3/2/2012**, which is why it was last.

Comment: Adam you were right, instead of looking at my faulty output it seems you actually ran my code and caught my mistake of looking at code for 5 hours straight...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to convert back and forth. Just do it once. Sort your list first, and only then convert to string.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to string and converting back might cause that result. Why don't you add x,y,w,z to your list directly?

```
List<DateTime> ldtBites = new List<DateTime>();
ldtBites.Add(DateTime.Parse("3/1/2012 10:56"));
ldtBites.Add(DateTime.Parse("3/1/2012 17:03"));
ldtBites.Add(DateTime.Parse("3/1/2012 1:38"));
ldtBites.Add(DateTime.Parse("3/1/2012 5:33"));
ldtBites.Sort();

foreach (DateTime dt in ldtBites)
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Output:

3/1/2012 1:38:00 AM

3/1/2012 5:33:00 AM

3/1/2012 10:56:00 AM

3/1/2012 5:03:00 PM

Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score -1):

Above will work only if all the date are same, in case the date are also different you should do the following...

```
var sortedDates = dates.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

or else Don't want to use, or don't know Linq then you can go for following..

```
static List SortAscending(List list)
{
list.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
return list;
}

static List SortDescending(List list)
{
list.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));
return list;
}
```